# Issue with lag out in ATOM : continues to show: 200 zzz...after i upload to website via ftp

Tags: ftp, atom-editor, connectivity

I am starting to work with Atom and was uploading my web template to Host Gator via Atom through Remote FTP package and it keeps giving me this code non stop. I was able to successfully upload the folder, but it continues to do this if I reconnect or disconnect. I've searched all over and I can't find the issue anywhere. Hopefully you guys can give me a hand. Thanks!

[image: screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0):

This is just the standard message you get that your site is connected and no uploading or downloading is happening.